# Compare if value is within range of number mysql

Tags: php, mysql, max, min

In my database i have 2 columns namely: `Min and Max` they are varchar and they have number values which i need to compare with. My query is something like this

`SELECT * FROM Pricing_tbl WHERE Productid='10'`

and i have this to compare the price

```
while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($marketval > $selected_row['Min'] && $marketval < $selected_row['Max']) {
        $price[] = array('price_level' => $selected_row['price_level']);
    }
}
```

This is ok if values of `Min` and `Max` are always numbers. But there is an instance where the value of `Max` is `above`. How to compare this situation?

Example values will be

[image]

Or should i just change the `Max` value. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: MySQL doesn't do math on strings, you'll need to cast them if you still want to retain that column type, or change the column type.

Comment: should store them as doubles, not varchar

Comment: My problem is when the value is comparing to the last one where there is a min value but the max value is above. I cant compare that one and i get error. How do i deal with that situation?@Fred-ii-

Comment: Ask *Diablo* down below. Oh... that sounded weirdly.

Comment: @Dagon my problem is comparing the max value when max value is equal to `above` this where i get error how do i deal with it

Comment: well that's one of your problems. storeing data in the wrong field type is another

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding why you'd want to have a row containing the word "above" in the first place; *why is that?*. If the intention is to mark a row as going above a certain number, then why not just have an additional column marking it as such? You could then add a condition in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you suggest that i add a column in the database?would it be very tedious to do?i need to check first that column to see if the value is beyond the upper limit?please enlighten me

Comment: Just add a column and set your present columns to a format that MySQL will be able to do math on. Plus, not knowing what you consider as "above" makes this a tad unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a maximum of `above` means all the way to infinity and you want to keep the data as is <sup>1</sup>, you can just change the condition:

```
$marketval > $selected_row['Min'] && $marketval < $selected_row['Max']
```

into something like:

```
$marketval >= $selected_row['Min'] &&
    ($selected_row['Max'] == 'above' || $marketval < $selected_row['Max'])
```

In other words a value is considered under the maximum *always* if the maximum is the word `above`. Otherwise the actual (original) comparison decides.

PHP short-circuiting on logical operators will ensure that the second half of the `or` section will never be evaluated if the first half is true.

Note the change I made to the minimum comparison as well, the use of `>=` rather than `>`. As it was, a value like `300000.01` would not have been caught.

You *may* also want to coerce the numerics in the comparisons with `$marketValue`. If both `$marketValue` and `$selectedRow['whatever']` are strings, I *think* they'll still use numeric comparison but I usually try to be explicit so I don't have to think about it :-)

---

<sup>1</sup> There are probably better ways to do this, other than storing what's *mostly* numeric data as strings just because you want to be able to store the value `'above'`.

Both methods below involve converting the column type to a numeric one which will allow better comparisons, *including having the DBMS itself work it out rather than having to get all data and post-process it with PHP.* Data manipulation is what a DBMS does best so it's generally better to leave that manipulation up to the DBMS for efficiency.

The first is to put a ridiculously large number in the maximum for the 'above' row so that your simple 'in between min and max' check will work. Using the DBMS itself to get the pricing level would be a simple:

```
select   pricing_level
  from   pricing_tbl
 where   product_id = '10'
   and   $market_val >= minval
   and   $market_val < maxval
```

That will give you a single row containing the correct pricing level.

The second is to store NULL in that column instead of a string. A nullable numeric column will still work with a slight modification:

```
select   pricing_level
  from   pricing_tbl
 where   product_id = '10'
   and   $market_val >= minval
   and   ($market_val < maxval or maxval is null)
```

In both those cases, you may want to translate the upper region (large number or null) to and from the word `above` when presenting or editing the table itself. This will make the process look the same even though the underlying data has changed.

Answer (score 0):

> i have 2 columns namely: Min and Max they are varchar

this is wrong. It should be int or at least decimal values

> My query is something like this

this is wrong. Your query should include $marketval to do all the calcs on the database side.

> here is an instance where the value of Max is above.

this is wrong. No numerical column should ever contain a string. you can store a big number there. or a NULL, but not a string.

Comment: That is more clear i will work all the suggestion you made as they are very clear and i understand them. I just want to know the pros and cons like compare to this solution why is it better than what i have right now just a short explanation would do happy coding